# Double Seasonal Holt winter method using dshw

Tags: forecasting

I have a two weeks data set which have intraday and intraweek cycles so I decided to use dshw in r. Although it gave me a pretty good MAE and RMSE, when I wanted to see SSE, it showed me a null value. Does it mean that Im using a wrong model for my dataset?I only used auto.arima command to see the best fitted model but the recommended model did not provide any seasonality values while the time series plot clearly shows seasonality in hours of a day and days of a week. Hence I switched to dshw. On the other hand, what is the commend to find predictions for the next cycles? I tried command "predict" but it did not work.

Thanks

Comment: with 2 weeks of data, I would use no change model or naive model as opposed to dshw.

Comment: I have a two years of hourly data and I just wanted to see how forecasting methods work so I picked two weeks. Hence, naive model does not work for me.